# Image not uploading in my files/folder inside hostinger

Tags: php, web-hosting, image-upload

I'm uploading an image on my website but the image is not saving to my folder/files. But there is no error, it just not uploading i tried many kinds of path but still not working.

I tried all of this use:

```
if($_POST) { 
$image = $_FILES["image"]["name"];

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], 'pictures/'.$_FILES["image"]["name"]);

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], 'public_html/pictures/'.$_FILES["image"]["name"]);

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], '/home/u125743903/domains/srmsbatangas.online
/pictures/'.$_FILES["image"]["name"]);

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], '/home/u125743903/domains/srmsbatangas.online
/public_html/pictures/'.$_FILES["image"]["name"]);
```

But nothing seems work. Is there any way to upload my image to my folder?

Comment: Well, what is the error message you get?

Comment: It doesn't show any error. It just that the image is not uploading to the folder. Or the path is different when hosting?

Comment: Take a look into your http server's error log file. That is where php usually logs errors to.

Comment: About the path ... you'd need to ask your provider what the base path is set to.